# How to remove subdirectories from path

Tags: makefile

I don't really know anything about make or makefile scripts, so I'm hoping someone can tell me what I need to change. There is a common makefile script included in all of the others, and this specific piece of the code seems to be responsible for processing the list of source files (DLL_OBJS) and setting up the target to compile them:

```
ifdef DLL_TARGET
DLL_REAL_OBJS=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(DLL_OBJS:=.$(OBJ))) $(DLL_VERSION_OBJS)
DLL_OUTPUT_FILE=$(OBJDIR)/$(LIBPREFIX)$(DLL_TARGET).$(DYNAMIC_LIB_SUFFIX)
$(DLL_OUTPUT_FILE): $(DLL_REAL_OBJS) $(DLL_NONPARSED_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CC_SHARED_LIB_FLAGS) $(LD_DYNAMIC) \
        \
        $(LD_DASH_O)$(DLL_OUTPUT_FILE) \
        \
        $(DLL_REAL_OBJS) $(DLL_NONPARSED_OBJS) \
                $(DLL_EXTRA) $(PRELIB) $(LD_FLAGS) \
        $(DLL_REAL_LIBS) $(DLL_NONPARSED_LIBS) $(LD_LIBS) $(DLL_OPTION)
ifdef EMBED_MANIFEST
ifndef SUPPRESS_MANIFEST_DLL
    $(PREMANIFEST) $(MT) \
        \
        $(MANIFESTFLAGS) /outputresource:"$(DLL_OUTPUT_FILE);#2" /manifest $(DLL_OUTPUT_FILE).manifest
endif
endif
endif # DLL_TARGET
```

The problem is if I do this:

```
DLL_OBJS=subdir/main
```

Then it will try to write the main.obj file to `WINNT5.0_DBG.OBJ/subdir/main.obj`, whereas I want it to go to `WINNT5.0_DBG.OBJ/main.obj`. How can I modify the code above to exclude the subdirectory portion of the source file from the object file output path? I suspect the changes will need to happen to the `DLL_REAL_OBJS` variable.

Note that `DLL_OBJS` could be a list of items, like:

```
DLL_OBJS=\
  subdir/main\
  subdir/foo\
  bar\
  another_source
```

Let me know if any important information is missing and I will do my best to update my question with it.

Comment: Do you know what version of Make you're using? (You can find out by `make -v`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GNUMake, just modify the second line:

```
DLL_REAL_OBJS=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(notdir $(DLL_OBJS:=.$(OBJ)))) $(DLL_VERSION_OBJS)
```